# Wireless Capability Is Turned Off

Tags: windows-7, networking, wireless-networking, laptop

I have tried many ways to turn on the wireless capability, but finally it can't make it. I do not know what happened. Last month I just sent it to the shop for the same problem. Is it a driver problem or is my laptop problem. I can use cable to connect to the internet. I mostly use wifi to connect because my cable is in another room as my work place is infront of the house and it does not have the cable there.

my laptop is MSI CR420
window 7

Answer (score 1):

Worth a try:

Click on Start Menu and right click on Computer

Click on Manage

Click on Device Manager in the left pane

Click on Network adapters

Double click on the wireless adapter to show properties. Go to the Advanced tab and select Radio Power and make sure it shows Enabled.

Answer (score 0):

check the below options:

1. Does the wireless adapter was installed correctly?
2. The wireless switch is ON or OFF?
3. Check in BIOS for the wireless installation and enable/disable.